# How to add third-party services in lazy-load module in Angular? On example of TranslateService(@ngx-translate) and OverlayModule

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

There is fork of "Minko Gechev" [Route-level code splitting in Angular sample app](https://web.dev/route-level-code-splitting-in-angular/#sample-application) with Translation and Overlay injections.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";
import { ComponentType, Overlay, OverlayConfig } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";

import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OverlayService {

  constructor(public overlay: Overlay) {}
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nyan',
  template: '<img src="/assets/nyan.png">',
  styleUrls: ['./nyan.component.css']
})
export class NyanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private cookieService:CookieService,
    private translateService:TranslateService,
    //private overlayService: OverlayService
  ){
     // No provider for Overlay! trouble 
    //  const overlayRef = this.overlayService.overlay.create();
    //  //touch overlay
    //  console.log(overlayRef);

  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    // it was same trouble for cookieService but it's gone
     const lang=this.cookieService.get('lang')||'en';
     //touch cookieService
     console.log(lang);

    this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translateService.use(lang);
    // NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateStore! patch from https://gitmemory.com/issue/ngx-translate/core/883/532257699
    // does not work.
    this.translateService.store.onLangChange.subscribe((lang) => this.translateService.use(lang));

  }

}
```

The error I got was:

> "Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TranslateService -> TranslateStore]: in lazy module

or

> "ERROR
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken cdk-connected-overlay-scroll-strategy -> Overlay]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken cdk-connected-overlay-scroll-strategy -> Overlay]:
>   NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!"

for version of "Overlay components uncommented".

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ajkykc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnyan%2Fnyan.component.ts).

Comment: You should read up on the documentation of ngx-translate. You're already missing the `TranslationModule` import, as well as initialization. Check here: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage

Comment: sorry I think you missed that file:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ajkykc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnyan%2Fnyan.module.ts

and it was done  by: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#lazy-loaded-modules

Answer (score 3):

To use `TranslateService` in lazy modules you should first add in your `AppModule`: 
`imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(), HttpClientModule]`

Using forRoot will inject TraslateService on your app-level as singleton.

And for using Overlay in your `OverlayService` you should remove `providedIn: 'root';` and add OverlayService to your NyanModule providers:

```
 providers:[
    CookieService,
    OverlayService
  ]
```

Because for using OverlayModule which is imported in your lazy module, this service should be a part of this module.

Comment: yes, It solves the issue, thank you.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ajkykc-x5k6xs

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you didn't include `TranslateService` in your `app.module.ts` `providers` array like this

```
providers : [TranslateService, TranslateStore  ]
```

Comment: no, it is not a solution. 
however, It gives me a clue: it needs to add TranslateStore as a provider.
https://github-ajkykc-7atpmd.stackblitz.io

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer. Accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, my solution is based on Valentin's solution and the one I provide in Fahad's comment:

it needs:
add to AppModule: imports: [HttpClientModule],
add to NyanModule:

```
...
  providers:[
    CookieService,
    OverlayService,
    TranslateService,
    TranslateStore // fix the translateStore issue
  ]
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ajkykc-9astlv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnyan%2Fnyan.module.ts

there is still a lack: I do not want HttpClientModule in appModule